Not able to capture the value of dropdown inside AG-GRID in Angular
enter code hereIn Angular I am not able to capture value of  dropdown selected value inside   AG-Grid .
I am able to capture all other values in the AG-Grid except dropdown value.
Dropdown is a separate component and it is added via cellRenderer  property of columnDefs.
here is my code of parent as well as child component


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Customer } from '../../customer/Models/customer.model';
import { CustomerService } from '../../customer/services/customer.service';
import { CustomerPaymentTermsService } from '../../customerpaymentterms/services/customer-payment-terms.service';
import { CustomerPaymentTerms } from '../../customerpaymentterms/Models/customerpaymentterms.model';
import { ProductService } from '../../Product/Services/product.service';
import { Product } from '../../Product/Models/product.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TradeinitiationService } from '../services/tradeinitiation.service';
import { AddTradeInitiation } from '../Models/AddTradeTransaction.model';
import { Supplier } from '../../customer/Models/supplier.model';
import { getCustomerrequirementlineitems } from '../Models/getCustomerrequirementlineitems.model';
import { SuppliercelleditorcomponentComponent } from '../../suppliercelleditor/suppliercelleditorcomponent/suppliercelleditorcomponent.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-trade-initiation',
  templateUrl: './create-trade-initiation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-trade-initiation.component.css']
})
export class CreateTradeInitiationComponent implements OnInit {
  id?: number;
  gridOptions: any;
  customername?: string |undefined;
  customerid ?:string;
  tradeForm: FormGroup;
  customers: Customer[] = [];
  customerpaymnetterms: CustomerPaymentTerms[] = [];
   products:Product[]=[];
   refereno ?:number|undefined;
   rowData: any[] = [];
  customerSearchControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  customerpaymenttermsSearchControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filteredCustomers: Customer[] = []; // Initialize filteredCustomers properly filteredCustomers: Customer[] = []; // Initialize filteredCustomers properly
  filteredCustomerpaymentterms: CustomerPaymentTerms[] = [];
  gridApi: any;
  productSearchcontrol :FormControl =new FormControl();
  filteredProducts :Product[]=[];
  userForm: any;
  suppliers:Supplier[]=[];
  filteredsupplier :Supplier[]=[];
cuastomerrequorementlineitems :getCustomerrequirementlineitems[]=[];
supplierSearchControl :FormControl=new FormControl();
errorMessage: string | null = null;

model:AddTradeInitiation;
 cellClassRules = {
  "cell-pass": (params: { value: number; }) => params.value >= 60,
  "cell-fail": (params: { value: number; }) => params.value < 60
};
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Product ID', field: 'productId' },
    { headerName: 'Product Name', field: 'name', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: false },
    { headerName: 'Selling Price', field: 'sellingprice', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: false , editable: true},
    { headerName: 'Buying Price', field: 'buyingprice', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: false , editable: true,cellClass: 'editablecell'},
    { headerName: 'Qty', field: 'qty', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: false , editable: true,
    
      valueGetter: this.defaultQtyValueGetter,

     cellClass: 'ecell',
      maxWidth: 90,
      },

    { headerName: 'Supplier', field: 'Supplier',width:400, sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: false, editable:true, cellRenderer: 'linkRenderer',


      cellRendererParams: {
        supplierSelected: this.onSupplierSelected.bind(this),
        
      }



     },
    // Add more columns as needed with floatingFilter
  ];
  defaultQtyValueGetter(params: any): any {
    // Example of setting a default value
    return params.data.qty ? params.data.qty : 0;
  }
  onGridReady(params: any): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }


 








constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private customerService: CustomerService, private customerpaymentservice:CustomerPaymentTermsService, private productservice:ProductService,private route: ActivatedRoute, private tradeinitiationservice:TradeinitiationService) {
this.model={
  tInitationid :"",
    customerRequirementid:"",
    tcustomerid :0,
    CustomerPaymentMethodid:0,
    transactionInitationStatusid :1,
    TInitationDate: '',

}
    this.tradeForm = this.fb.group({
      tradeInitiationNumber:this.refereno,
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      customer: ['', Validators.required],
      crReferenceNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      customerpaymentterms: ['', Validators.required],
      product :[''],
      sellingprice :[''],
      buyingprice :[''],
      qty :[''],
      supplier:['']
      });

    this.customerSearchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // Filter customers based on the search query
      this.filteredCustomers = this.filterCustomers(value);
    });
    this.customerpaymenttermsSearchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // Filter customers based on the search query
      this.filteredCustomerpaymentterms = this.filterCustomerpaymentterms(value);
    });

this.supplierSearchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{

this.filteredsupplier =this.fsupplier(value);

})





this.productSearchcontrol.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
this.filteredProducts = this.filterProducts(value);

});

}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.gridOptions = {
      components: {
        linkRenderer: SuppliercelleditorcomponentComponent,
     
      },
      // Other grid options
    };
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      // Extract the ID parameter value
      this.id = +params['crid'];
      this.customername =params['customerName'];
      this.tradeinitiationservice.getcustomeridfromcustomername(params['customerName']).subscribe({
        next :(response) =>{
        console.log("cuatsdhbf bf"+response);
        this.customerid =response;
        console.log("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn bf"+this.customerid);
        this.tradeForm.get('customer')?.setValue(this.customerid);
    








        }
      });

      this.tradeinitiationservice.getcustomerrequirementlineitemdetails(params['crid']).subscribe({
        next: (response: getCustomerrequirementlineitems[]) => {

          console.log(response);
          response.forEach(item => {
            const rowDataItem = {
              productId: item.productid,
              name: item.productname,
              // map other properties as needed
            };
            this.rowData.push(rowDataItem);
            this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
          });
      
          // If you need to see the results
          console.log(this.rowData);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.error('Error fetching customer requirement line items', err);
        }
      });







  //alert(this.id);
});
this.tradeinitiationservice.getLastTradeInitiationRefNo().subscribe({
  next :(response) =>{
  console.log(response);
  this.refereno=response;

  //alert(this.refereno);
  this.tradeForm.patchValue({
  tradeInitiationNumber: this.refereno
  });













  }
});
    this.customerService.getallCustomers().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.customers = response;
        this.filteredCustomers = response; // Initialize filteredCustomers with the full list
      }
    });


this.customerService.getallsuppliers().subscribe({
next:(response)=>{

  this.suppliers =response;
  this.filteredsupplier=response;

console.log(this.filteredsupplier);

}


})








    this.customerpaymentservice.getAllCustomerPaymnetTerms().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.customerpaymnetterms = response;
        this.filteredCustomerpaymentterms = response; // Initialize filteredCustomers with the full list
      }
    });

    this.productservice.getAllProducts().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.products = response;
        this.filteredProducts = response; // Initialize filteredCustomers with the full list
      }
    });
  }
  filterCustomerpaymentterms(value: string): CustomerPaymentTerms[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.customerpaymnetterms.filter(customerpaymnetterms => customerpaymnetterms.cPaymentmethodName?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

filterProducts(value:string): Product[]{
const filtervalue =value.toLowerCase();
return this.products.filter(products=>products.name?.toLowerCase().includes(filtervalue));
}

  filterCustomers(value: string): Customer[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.customers.filter(customer => customer.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

  fsupplier(value:string):Supplier[]{
const filtervalue =value.toLowerCase();
return this.suppliers.filter(supp=>supp.name?.toLowerCase().includes(filtervalue));


  }

  addDataToGrid(event:Event):void{


  }




 



  onSupplierSelected(event: { value: string, rowIndex: number }) {
    console.log('Selected Supplier:', event.value);
alert(event.value);

    // Update rowData with the selected supplier value at the specified rowIndex
    this.rowData[event.rowIndex].supplierid = event.value;

    // Optionally, you can update the grid with the new rowData
    if (this.gridApi) {
      this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
  //alert("dsfmsdfsd");
  //this.model.tInitationid =this.userForm.value.tradeInitiationNumber;
  



  
  alert(this.id );
  alert(this.tradeForm.get('supplier')?.value)
  this.model.customerRequirementid = (this.id ?? '').toString();
  this.model.TInitationDate =this.tradeForm.get('date')?.value;
  this.model.tcustomerid=this.tradeForm.get('customer')?.value;
  this.model.CustomerPaymentMethodid =this.tradeForm.get('customerpaymentterms')?.value;
  this.model.transactionInitationStatusid =1
  this.model.tInitationid = this.tradeForm.get('tradeInitiationNumber')?.value;              
  this.tradeinitiationservice.createTradeInitationheader(this.model)
  .subscribe({
  next: (response) => {






    
    if (this.gridApi) {
      // Get all row nodes from the grid
    
      this.gridApi.forEachNode((node: { data: any; }) => {
        const rowDataItem = {
          productId: node.data.productId,
          name: node.data.name,
          sellingprice: node.data.sellingprice,
          buyingprice: node.data.buyingprice,
          qty: node.data.qty,
          supplierid: node.data.supplierid // Ensure this matches with your grid column definition
        };
        console.log (rowDataItem);
        this.rowData.push(node.data);
      });

      // Set rowData in your component for further processing
      this.rowData = this.rowData;

      console.log ( this.rowData );


    }









 





  } , error: (error: { status: number; error: string | null; }) => {
    if (error.status === 409) { // Check if HTTP status code is 409 Conflict
      this.errorMessage = error.error; // Set error message received from the backend
    } else {
      this.errorMessage = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.'; // Generic error message
    }
  }








});

 
  }
}



here is my html part of parent componenet.


<div class="container">

  <h2  style ="font-weight: bold;">TRADE INITIATION FORM</h2>
<hr/>
  <form [formGroup]="tradeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-container">


    <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="error-message mt-3">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>




    <div class="form-row"  style="margin-top: 3rem;">
      <div class="row">
      <div  class="col-md-5 col-lg-56">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field custom-width">
        <mat-label>Trade Initiation Number</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="tradeInitiationNumber" required>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div  class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
        <mat-label>CR Reference Number</mat-label>
        <input matInput [value]="id" readonly>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
<div  class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">

</div>
<div  class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
  <button mat-raised-button color="warning" type="submit">Reset</button>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
        <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date" required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="row">
      <div  class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
        <mat-label>Customer</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="customer" required>
          <!-- Include ngx-mat-select-search inside mat-select -->
          <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="customerSearchControl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
          <!-- Display mat-option for each customer -->
          <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of filteredCustomers" [value]="customer.id">
            {{ customer.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
      <mat-label>Customer Payment Terms </mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="customerpaymentterms" required>
        <!-- Include ngx-mat-select-search inside mat-select -->
        <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="customerpaymenttermsSearchControl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <!-- Display mat-option for each customer -->
        <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of filteredCustomerpaymentterms" [value]="customer.cPaymentmethodId
        ">
          {{ customer.cPaymentmethodName }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>

 
<hr/>
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<mat-form-field class="form-field"  appearance ="outline">
<mat-label>Products</mat-label>
<mat-select  formControlName="product"  >
<ngx-mat-select-search  [formControl]="productSearchcontrol"  > </ngx-mat-select-search>
<mat-option   *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts" [value]="product.productId
">  {{product.name}}    </mat-option>

</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
    <mat-label>Qty</mat-label>
    <input matInput  formControlName="qty">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
    <mat-label>Selling Price</mat-label>
    <input matInput    formControlName="sellingprice">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
    <mat-label>Buying Price</mat-label>
    <input matInput  formControlName="buyingprice">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">

  <mat-form-field class="form-field"  appearance ="outline">
    <mat-label>Supplier</mat-label>
    <mat-select  formControlName="supplier"  >
    <ngx-mat-select-search  [formControl]="supplierSearchControl"  > </ngx-mat-select-search>
    <mat-option   *ngFor="let sup of filteredsupplier" [value]="sup.sId
    ">  {{sup.name}}    </mat-option>
    
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>



</div>







<div class="col-md-1">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" class="custom-button"   (click)="addDataToGrid($event)">+</button>
</div>

</div>

 </div>


 <div class="ag-theme-alpine" >
  <ag-grid-angular 
  style="width:1300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;"
  class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowHeight]="55"
  [rowData]="rowData"  
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"  [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
 </div>
<div>

  <p>Percentage: {{ 56 | number:'1.2-3' }}</p>
</div>
  
  </form>
</div>



here is the .ts and html file of child component.


import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellEditorAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellEditorParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { CustomerService } from '../../customer/services/customer.service';
import { Supplier } from '../../customer/Models/supplier.model';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-suppliercelleditorcomponent',
  templateUrl: './suppliercelleditorcomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./suppliercelleditorcomponent.component.css']
})
export class SuppliercelleditorcomponentComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp, OnInit  {
  
  params!: ICellEditorParams;
  selectedSupplier!: string;
  supplierSearchControl :FormControl=new FormControl();



  filteredsupplier:Supplier[]=[];
  tradeForm1: FormGroup;

  suppliers :Supplier[]=[];
  @Output() supplierSelected = new EventEmitter<any>();
  onDropdownClick(){

alert("zsdnsdbfds");

  }
 
  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.tradeForm1 = this.fb.group({
   
      supplier:['']
      });


      this.supplierSearchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        // Filter customers based on the search query
        this.filteredsupplier = this.fsupplier(value);
      });





  }

  fsupplier(value:string){
    const filtervalue =value.toLowerCase();
    return this.suppliers.filter(supp=>supp.name?.toLowerCase().includes(filtervalue));
    
    
      }


  agInit(params: ICellEditorParams<any, any, any>): void {
  this.params=params;
  this.selectedSupplier = this.params.value;

  }
  getValue() {
    return this.selectedSupplier;
  }
  refresh?(params: ICellEditorParams<any, any, any>): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  afterGuiAttached?(): void {

  }
  isPopup?(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  getPopupPosition?(): 'over' | 'under' | undefined {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  isCancelBeforeStart?(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  isCancelAfterEnd?(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  focusIn?(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  focusOut?(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.customerService.getallsuppliers().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.suppliers = response;
        this.filteredsupplier = response; // Initialize filteredCustomers with the full list
      }
    });
  }
  onSupplierSelected(event: any): void {
  this.selectedSupplier = event.value;
  alert(this.selectedSupplier);
  const rowIndex = this.params.rowIndex;

  alert(rowIndex);
  this.supplierSelected.emit({ value: this.selectedSupplier, rowIndex });
}
}



here is the html code of child componenet.


<form [formGroup]="tradeForm1" style="width: 10px;height:10px">
    <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>supplier</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="supplier"  (selectionChange)="onSupplierSelected($event)">>
        <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="supplierSearchControl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let sup of filteredsupplier" [value]="sup.sId">
          {{sup.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>



on button click inside main component I am able to capture all the values of ag-grid except  those in dropdown.  conole.log is showing all values inside ag-grid except dropdown supplier ..it is showing undefined

here is the console.log


It looks like in the dropdown value is set at "sId" and you are reading supplierid. This mismatch could be the issue. Otherwise, it would be helpful if you replicate the issue in stackblitz and share.

that didnt work
